# Where is this kotlin expression described in the documentation?

Tags: kotlin

I have this kotlin function, and I undersatand that the expression : row.map(Char::digitToInt), converts a Char into an Int.
What I need, is more explanation regarding Char::digitToInt.
How can I relate the use of :: in the kotlin documentation?
Thank's in advance for your reply.

```
private fun parseInput(input: List<String>): Array<IntArray> =
input.map { row: String ->
    row.map(Char::digitToInt).toIntArray()
}.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: It's the [second bullet here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type). Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#class-references) this is a class reference:

> Class References: The most basic reflection feature is getting the
> runtime reference to a Kotlin class. To obtain the reference to a
> statically known Kotlin class, you can use the class literal syntax:

```
val c = TestClass::class  //The reference is a value of type KClass.
```

> Note that a Kotlin class reference is not the same as a Java class
> reference. To obtain a Java class reference, use the .java property on
> a KClass instance.

It’s also the syntax for method references as in this simple example:

```
myList.forEach(::println)
```

It refers to println defined in Kotlin Standard library.

Comment: Thank's to you, Sweeper and Halifax. So I understand that ::digitToInt refers to the function digitToInt(), but I hardly understand that the whole expression is able to specify a transformation. What I need is a phrase to read this expression. Would it be, for example: this is the definition of a function that takes a Char, pass it to the digitToInt() function, and returns an Int? Is it similar to: (a) -> digitToInt(a)

Comment: `row.map(Char::digitToInt)` As you can see from the source code, it is finally converted into a collection list ：
```     // omit more
  CharSequence.map(...) => mapTo(ArrayList<R>(length), transform)

 CharSequence.mapTo(...) {
    ...  destination.add(transform(item))
}

```

`Char::digitToInt` Its source code can be seen:  Returns the numeric value of the decimal digit that this Char represents 
```
public fun Char.digitToInt(): Int {
    return digitOf(this, 10) //omit more
}
```

Comment: @PhilippePONS it is equivalent to `a -> a.digitToInt()` which is what I think you meant. If you hover over it in IntelliJ and do `Show Context actions` one of the options is `Convert reference to lambda` which will convert it to `it.digitToInt` which is just a shorter form of ` `a -> a.digitToInt()`. References and lambdas are largely interchangeable, so it's a matter of taste which you find clearer to read.